# Powershell file comparison

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare two directories to find any differences between the directories (extra files, missing files, extra directories, etc).  The script I am using below generates the output, but what I would like to have the script do is print out the full path of any extra file or extra directory not just the file or directory itself.

So here, Test1 folder has two extra directories and two extra files not present in the Test directory.  So in the output I'd like to see the full path not just the names of the directories and files.

Current output -

ExtraDir1

ExtraDir2

Extra file1

Extra file2

Desired output -

/Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/Test1/ExtraDir1

/Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/Test1/ExtraDir2

/Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/ExtraFile1

/Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/Test1/ExtraDir2/ExtraFile2

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path /Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/Test
$Target = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path /Users/jb/Documents/PowerShell/Test1

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Target | %{
if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") {"$($_.InputObject) "}
} >> ./Results/ExtraDir.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FullName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname) of the input objects from `Get-ChildItem` to get the full path:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $Target | %{
  if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") {"$($_.InputObject.FullName) "}
} >> ./Results/ExtraDir.txt
```